AXI DMA ready signal is never high
I have written an AXI stream IP in VHDL in Vivado.  This is the simulation of the AXI Stream:

This is the block design:

the clock divider is a module I wrote to create the input for the custom IP.
The problem is that the AXI DMA never asserts the tready input high.
This is the AXI DMA settings:

This is the code in Vitis:
    #include "xaxidma.h"
    #include "xstatus.h"
    #include "sleep.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "platform.h"
    #include "xil_printf.h"
    #include "xparameters.h"
    #include "xil_types.h"
    #include "xil_assert.h"
    #include "stdbool.h"
    #define C_M_START_COUNT 32;
    #define DATA_ENTRIES 5
    #define TOTAL_BYTES (DATA_ENTRIES * sizeof(u32))

    u32 is_dma_halted (u32 base_addr, u32 offset_addr)
    {
        u32 Status;
        Status = XAxiDma_ReadReg (base_addr, offset_addr) & 0x1;
        return Status;
    }

    int main()
        {
        int Status, statusdma;
        XAxiDma Dma_inst;
        XAxiDma_Config *Dma_Config;
        xil_printf("PWM Capture\n");
        u32 response[DATA_ENTRIES] ;
        Dma_Config = XAxiDma_LookupConfig(XPAR_AXI_DMA_0_DEVICE_ID);
        if (Dma_Config== NULL)
        {
            xil_printf("XAxiDma_LookupConfig failed\n");
        }
        Status = XAxiDma_CfgInitialize(&Dma_inst, Dma_Config);
        if(Status != XST_SUCCESS)
        {
            xil_printf("XAxiDma_CfgInitialize failed\n");
        }

    // Ensure DMA is configured for simple mode
    if (XAxiDma_HasSg(&Dma_inst))
    {
        xil_printf("Device is configured in Scatter-Gather mode. Exiting.\n");
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }
    xil_printf("Printing results\n");
    while(1)
    {
        Status = XAxiDma_SimpleTransfer(&Dma_inst, (UINTPTR)response, TOTAL_BYTES , 
        XAXIDMA_DEVICE_TO_DMA);
        if (Status != XST_SUCCESS)
        {
            xil_printf("XAxiDma_SimpleTransfer 2 failed\n");
        }
        while ( XAxiDma_Busy(&Dma_inst, XAXIDMA_DEVICE_TO_DMA) )
        {
                /* Wait */
        }
        Xil_DCacheInvalidateRange((UINTPTR)response, TOTAL_BYTES);
        printf("response0: %u\n\r" , response[0] );
        printf("response1: %u\n\r" , response[1] );
        printf("response2: %u\n\r" , response[2] );
        printf("response3: %u\n\r" , response[3] );
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
    }

The problem is that in the ILA only the Tvalid is 1 and the tready that should be asserted via DMA is never high and when I read the status register of the DMA, the bit related to internal error is 1. What could I have possibly done wrong?
Considering the Simulation screenshot again, as can be seen when both Valid and ready are high, there  is a one clock cycle delay until we have the first data (30) but in subsequent cycles, there are 4 data in the TDATA and the 4th gets a Tlast. Could that be part of the problem?
the delay can't be removed because there is a condition that checkecks if valid and ready are both high and then the transmission starts. therefore the delay is inevitable.

I'm not sure I understand the tready that should be asserted via DMA is never high part of the question. This is because as far as can tell, the ILA capture shows M_AXIS_TREADY changing from low to high. Can the question be edited to clarify?

@ChesterGillon I have not added the picture of the ILA. That is simulation and I assigned tready high in my testbench.

Thanks for pointing out that I had misread the question, and was confusing the simulation picture for that of the ILA. Can you clarify what the packet size from the "PMWCaptureMasterStream" block is supposed to be? The simulation appears to show a packet size of 4 32-bit words, while DATA_ENTRIES used for the DMA transfer length in the Vitis code is set to 5. Does the behaviour change if DATA_ENTRIES is changed to 4?

PG021 description of DMAIntErr bit in the S2MM_STATUS (S2MM Status) register contains This error can also be caused if an under-run or over-run condition. If the packet size on the stream doesn't match that set in the DMA, I'm not sure if that could lead to a under-run or over-run. But this is a possible explanation for an error if the value of DATA_ENTRIES used in the Vitis code doesn't match the stream.

@ChesterGillon I wish to have packet sizes of 4. but for the reason I added at the end of my question I have 5 words in the first packet.  I tried with packet size of 5 5 hoping I'll get the first 5 words but still the tready was low

"... there is a condition that checkecks [sic] if valid and ready are both high and then the transmission starts. therefore the delay is inevitable." You're doing AXI incorrectly. VALID should not be asserted if the data bus is not in fact valid. But that isn't what is preventing the DMA from asserting READY -- it should be doing that regardless of the state of VALID. You need to focus on why it is reporting an error, which has noting to do with what may or may not be happening on the streaming side.
